# amazon alb and basic auth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-elb

I have a simple site in fargate and an alb.    I want to throw a simple basic auth on top of it - just a single hardwired username and password.  Is there an easy way to do this?

I tried going to cognito - creating a user pool, and attaching it to the site, but there were questions like "callback url" - which i just set to the same url and "signout url" that I wasn't sure about and when I managed to click a set of things that allowed me to add it, and add a listener to my https endpoint - it just gives a "redirect_mismatch" when I try to get in.

Is there any way to do what I want *without editing the underlying system in any way*?

Comment: ok - I found some magic incantation to make it work - but I'm still not entirely sure what I did - and it still seems way more complicated than it needs to be

Comment: Would be useful to share at least some of the details of that "magic incantation", so that other users could benefit as well. ;)

Comment: yeah - I set cognito as essentially a rule on the listener on the load balancer..   However - I have since dumped it and just gone to nginx and basic auth inside the container as cognito went down on us several times

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did the following tests using ALB and CloudFront - HTTPS for Browsers only

1. Encode credentials user=`user` and password=`password`

   ```bash
   echo -n 'user:password' | base64

   dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
   ```
2. Create ALB with the listener rule HTTP header `Authorization` is `Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==`
   [image: AWS ALB Listener rules]

3. Place ALB behind CloudFront and [forward `Authorization` header](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-selecting)
4. Test result using curl

   ```bash
   # Authentication option
   curl -u 'user:password' https://d3anlpzrykthss.cloudfront.net
   Hello from f86c5f9e0395

   # In-url password
   curl https://user:password@d3anlpzrykthss.cloudfront.net
   Hello from f86c5f9e0395

   # Headers
   curl -H 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==' https://d3anlpzrykthss.cloudfront.net
   Hello from f86c5f9e0395

   # Wrong password
   curl -u 'user:wrong' https://d3anlpzrykthss.cloudfront.net
   Not authorized
   ```
5. Not clear how to make it to work in Browsers - [Can I use HTTP Basic Auth in URLs?](https://danq.me/2021/09/07/http-basic-auth-urls/)

   ```bash
   # Firefox / Chrome / Safari
   https://user:password@d3anlpzrykthss.cloudfront.net
   Not authorized
   ```

Comment: Why it doesn't work in browsers: ALB unfortunately doesn't support to send headers in the fixed response, so we cannot add the "WWW-Authenticate" header, which would be required so that browsers use Basic Auth. You can make it work e.g. with a Lambda attached to CloudFront though, which allows to set response headers.

Comment: Isn't that a different story, when you do not provide/miss credentials and browser ask you for them and in URL credentials should just work?

[WWW-Authenticate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate)

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible. The supported methods are:

- OIDC
- Cognito: which supports common social IdPs and corporate identities like LDAP, SAML, etc.

Please refer to the [ALB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html) for more information.

A common solution for this is to deploy an nginx server between the user and your service and configure it to provide the basic authentication layer you need.